# Querying for rows with no foreign key (NOT NULL Foreign key) pointing to them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read several posts describing a problem very similar to mine but i haven't been able to solve my issue yet. This is it:

There are tables A, B, C and D. Table D is referenced by the other 3 tables and only table (A) has a 'nullable' foreign key and what I need to find are the rows in D that are NOT being pointed/referenced by any of the other 3 tables. So far I've been able to filter all rows including those I want to find with this code:

```
SELECT D.Id as Id, A.Id as A_Id, B.Id as B_Id, C.Id as C_Id
FROM D
LEFT OUTER JOIN A --this is the nullable one
ON D.Id = A.D_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON D.Id = B.D_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
ON D.Id = C.D_Id
```

Although I can see the rows I need in the result by looking at them and they display the foreign-key-field as being null if I try to filter by `IS NULL` then I get no results at all, this is the query I used:

```
SELECT D.Id as Id, A.Id as A_Id, B.Id as B_Id, C.Id as C_Id
FROM D
LEFT OUTER JOIN A --this is the nullable one
ON D.Id = A.D_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON D.Id = B.D_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
ON D.Id = C.D_Id
WHERE A.D_Id IS NULL AND B.D_Id IS NULL AND C.D_Id IS NULL
```

Please any help will be most appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

### Edit

I have tried this and it worked although it was a very different approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM D
WHERE     Id not in (Select D_Id from A) 
      and Id not in (Select D_Id from B) 
      and Id not in (Select D_Id from C)
```

Comment: Your second query looks correct...

Comment: [SQL Fiddle Proof!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8871c/2/0)

Comment: @Blim His second query should technically work fine as is with the data you put there. I guess without having the full table structure and what his data looks, that makes this harder to figure out.

Comment: yeap it is almost right. see my answer hi should check a not nullable column like A.Id,B.Id,C.Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query is <s>almost</s> correct!

Alternatively Instead of

`WHERE A.D_Id IS NULL AND B.D_Id IS NULL AND C.D_Id IS NULL`

I would use

`WHERE A.Id IS NULL AND B.Id IS NULL AND C.Id IS NULL`

```
SELECT D.Id as Id, A.Id as A_Id, B.Id as B_Id, C.Id as C_Id
FROM D
   LEFT OUTER JOIN A --this is the nullable one
      ON D.Id = A.D_Id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN B
      ON D.Id = B.D_Id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN C
      ON D.Id = C.D_Id
WHERE A.Id IS NULL AND B.Id IS NULL AND C.Id IS NULL
```

[Sql Fiddle Updated](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8871c/21/0)

Comment: This works, although I'm not sure why it does, could you explain please @Blim

Comment: @Luiso your query is right too! Are you sure you do the same thing in your real problem? Do you filter out the rows based on the columns you use in the ON clauses?

Comment: Yes @Blim, I tried it several times and every time I got the same empty response. I don't understand why yours work though

Comment: @Luiso I don't why yours don't as you can see in the updated fiddle both queries work!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an OR instead of AND for the is null to get what you want? It could be that it is null in the join from one of the tables and not null in the other.

```
SELECT D.Id as Id, A.Id as A_Id, B.Id as B_Id, C.Id as C_Id
FROM D
LEFT OUTER JOIN A --this is the nullable one
ON D.Id = A.D_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON D.Id = B.D_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
ON D.Id = C.D_Id
WHERE A.D_Id IS NULL OR B.D_Id IS NULL OR C.D_Id IS NULL
```

Edit: Does this give you the results you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM D
WHERE D.id NOT IN (SELECT D_id FROM A)
AND D.id NOT IN (SELECT D_id FROM B)
AND D.id NOT IN (SELECT D_id FROM C)
```

Comment: Sorry @SLin but the OR does not work for me, I want only the rows with no foreign key pointing to them and in this code I will get all with at least one foreign key not-pointing to them thank you very much for your fast response though

Comment: @Luiso Strange, that should work technically, can you try the second query and see if that gives you the proper results?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NOT EXISTS to exclude the table D entries that are referenced by the other tables?

```
SELECT 
    D.Id as Id
FROM 
    D
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE D.Id = A.D_Id)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE D.Id = B.D_Id)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM C WHERE  D.Id = C.D_Id);
```